# Decent tool for producing a glossary of technical terms

Tags: documentation, glossary

I'm currently developing the front end of a new CMS for a digital streaming company, the main problem the project has is keeping track of the technical language that has sprung up around it.

It currently involves around 60 staff in four countries, aside from a wiki (which has thus far failed to be kept up-to-date), anyone have any good tools or tips for building and maintaining a glossary for a project like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> aside from a wiki (which has thus far failed to be kept up-to-date)

This comment makes me pretty nervous about suggesting other solutions. Wiki's can come with their own problems, but keeping it up to date is not a problem inherent in the platform. It's a cultural or organizational problem. A wiki provides a very easy way to track and update data. If, today, you cannot keep it up to date, ask yourself how you will solve this problem if you change the tool?

Changing to another platform could solve things like: The wiki isn't scalable for that amount of data; we want to make controlled edits; we need to release in multiple languages; we need to release in other formats.

For the updating problem, try something simple to start, like assigning a dedicated team member to glossary maintenance. They don't have to be the only contributor, but if you have someone who is dedicated to paying some attention to this area you will have a much better chance of keeping things up to date.

In an untended garden, it's not the fault of the soil that you have no flowers.

Answer (score 2):

DITA has a glossary specialization. You can maintain a central company glossary in it. In individual company documents, you create a mini glossary topic then use a content reference to pull any terms you need into your document.

It does sound more like a version control issue though.